# Application layer in TCP

Tags: wcf, layer

What i know is that (HTTP,ftp,smtp) are some of the application layers, which will interact with tcp (transmission control protocol) to send data via receive data, but when using net.tcp:// in WCF what will be the default application layer protocol.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP, FTP are actually application layers means applications use them. any chatting application that communicates using reliable medium like TCP and send data binary encoded is also considered another application in application layer that has its own protocol of communication like ftp smtp has their own conventions. so simply net:tcp also communicate in binary on wire so it should be considered another application if not using any of the defined ports like 80,21 etc

> The NetTcpBinding generates a run-time communication stack by default,
>   which uses transport security, TCP for message delivery, and a binary
>   message encoding. This binding is an appropriate system-provided
>   choice for communicating over an Intranet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx

and for comparison with other bindings

http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=1085

And About Application Layer in TCP stack

> The Application layer is the layer that most common network-aware
>   programs use in order to communicate across a network with other
>   programs. Processes that occur in this layer are application specific;
>   data is passed from the network-aware program, in the format used
>   internally by this application, and is encoded into a standard
>   protocol.
>
> Some specific programs are considered to run in this layer. They
>   provide services that directly support user applications. These
>   programs and their corresponding protocols include HTTP (The World
>   Wide Web), FTP (File transport), SMTP (Email), SSH (Secure remote
>   login), DNS (Name <-> IP Address lookups) and many others.
>
> Once the data from an application has been encoded into a standard
>   application layer protocol it will be passed down to the next layer of
>   the IP stack.

http://www.starlancs.com/EducateMe/educate_IP_stack.html

notice the wording here application layer contains process/programs that consume data internally encoded into a standard protocol(protocol they can understand).

A protocol is just an agreement for communication. even you can build your own protocol for you application to communicate.

Hope this will help you understand.

Regards.

Comment: you mean that net:tcp is an application layer protocol designed for wcf

Comment: :) no net tcp is just a binding that supports data transmission in binary encoding. you can build you application using it and that application will be one applicaiton in app layer

Comment: Shoaib thanks for the replay....:) .. but there should be a protocol for sending messages through net.tcp? lets say if you are using HTTP binding.. the protocol (application layer) will be HTTP.

Comment: don't make yourself with the term protocol. http is just a name of port 80. we usually send plain text on this port. that plain text follows html standards from w3c.

Comment: a web browser is an application that communicate over port 80(http) and browser knows what he can expect in return from a web server. this is what http protocol standard comes to tell what does a request mean comming from browser